# how to share automatic to facebook and several times not only 1 time

Tags: php, facebook, share

I get from facebook some code to auto sharing , so i need to edit my code to get , auto sharing several times , not only 1 time....i need a help in how to make that issue , i let for you my code:

```
//-- Facebook API --//
require_once 'php-sdk/facebook.php';

//-- App Information --//
$app_id     = 'zzzzzzzzz';
$app_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$pageId= 'me';

// Create Facebook Instance
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => $app_id,
    'secret' => $app_secret,
    'cookie' => true
));

//-- To Facebook (Notice we ask for offline access) --//
if (empty($_REQUEST))
{
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'canvas' => 1,
        'fbconnect' => 0,
        'scope' => 'offline_access,publish_stream'
    ));
    header('Location:'.$loginUrl );
}
//-- From Facebook --//
else
{
    $user = $facebook->getUser();
    if($user)
    {
        $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
        $req =  array(
    'access_token' => $access_token,
    'message' => 'Jeremy Gibbs is a handsome lad!');

//-- Send post to Facebook --//
$res = $facebook->api('/'.$pageId.'/feed', 'POST', $req);
header("location: http://facebook.com/".$pageId."");
    }
}
```

so can u tell me how ?

Comment: Why are you wanting to share the same thing over and over again? Don't you think your users (and their Facebook friends) will get annoyed?

Comment: you are right , but they can ignore my app request :) , they will know from the first that my application will upload several times , ( not directly) , but maybe first time now , second time after 1 hour....and between everytime will be 1 hour for example...

Answer (score 0):

You can user cron jobs on your server OR use http://twitterfeed.com/